# Some rows are collapsed in DataGrid, I am getting issue in KeyBoard navigation

Tags: wpfdatagrid

I am using DataGrid, run time i make visible collapse some rows.
Suppose my 4th row's visibility is collapse, and my focus is on 3rd row, when i try to move on 5th row with the help of Down-Arrow key, it is not working. Same way if my focus on 5th row and want to move on 3rd row with Up-Arrow key, it is also not working.
Now, what should i do?

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a bug in .Net, there is a bug report [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/526014/keyboard-navigation-doesnt-work-when-the-wpf-datagrid-has-collapsed-or-hidden-rows).

One workaround is to use Attached behavior to handle the up and down selection. The following example requires the IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem to be set to true for the DataGrid.

Note! make sure you change the while condition to the appropriate way to determine if the item is collapsed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace DataGridGroupingTest
{
    class DataGridKeyboardNavigationAttachedBehavior
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty
                KeyboardKey
                    = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                        "IsKeyboardNavigationEnabled",
                        typeof(bool),
                        typeof(DataGridKeyboardNavigationAttachedBehavior),
                        new PropertyMetadata(
                            false,
                            OnIsKeyboardNavigationEnabledChanged));

        public static bool GetIsKeyboardNavigationEnabled(DependencyObject depObj)
        {
            return (bool)depObj.GetValue(KeyboardKey);
        }

        public static void SetIsKeyboardNavigationEnabled(DependencyObject depObj, bool value)
        {
            depObj.SetValue(KeyboardKey, value);
        }

        private static void OnIsKeyboardNavigationEnabledChanged(DependencyObject depObj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = depObj as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid != null)
            {
                dataGrid.PreviewKeyDown += dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown;
                dataGrid.IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem = true;
            }
        }

        static void dataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            DataGrid dataGrid = sender as DataGrid;
            if (dataGrid != null && dataGrid.CurrentCell != null)
            {
                if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down || e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up)
                {
                    ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dataGrid.Items);

                    int loopCount = 0;
                    do
                    {
                        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Down)
                        {
                            view.MoveCurrentToNext();
                            if (view.IsCurrentAfterLast)
                            {
                                view.MoveCurrentToFirst();
                                loopCount++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Up)
                        {
                            view.MoveCurrentToPrevious();
                            if (view.IsCurrentBeforeFirst)
                            {
                                view.MoveCurrentToLast();
                                loopCount++;
                            }
                        }
                    } while (((Person)view.CurrentItem).Boss != null && !((Person)view.CurrentItem).Boss.IsExpanded && loopCount < 2);

                    // We have to move the cell selection aswell.
                    dataGrid.CurrentCell = new DataGridCellInfo(view.CurrentItem, dataGrid.CurrentCell.Column);

                    e.Handled = true;
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have they fixed the bug? I'm still seeing it in my .NET 4.7 app.